# Security of Google Drive API Objects using Google Service Account Credentials in Client Side Code for Website

Tags: html, google-api, client-server, service-accounts

Is there a safe and secure way to setup the code and files/folders for a website where a Google Drive API object is created in the client side code using a Google Service Account Json credentials file?
I am working on a siteground hosted website and I want to make sure the Service account credentials do not get exposed in any way.